# Angular js- Setting headers in a ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set some customer headers in a service factory.  Here is the code:

```
angular.module('clinicalApp').factory('encounterService', function ($resource) {
  var EncounterService = $resource('http://localhost:port/v1/providers/:providerId', {providerId:'@id', port: ':8280'}, {
    search: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      headers: {
        'RemoteUser': 'billybob'
      }
    }
  });
  return EncounterService;
});
```

Here is the code that calls the service.

```
angular.module('clinicalApp').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, encounterService) {
  encounterService.search({
    limit: 2000,
    organizationId : '11110000'
  });
});
```

When I use this resource and everything works fine, but the header is not set on the ajax call, so I get a 401 in return.  What else do I have to do to set the headers?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure the other answers I received work, but I did not want to use $http, I wanted to use $resource.  To use resource with custom headers, I had to upgrade my Angular version.  I did not look into the source code to find the reason why, and I don't know what version this functionality changed. Right now I am using  v1.2.0-rc.2 and everything just worked.  It took a few changed in the app config, namely I had to name ngRoute as a dependency to make the version work, but then I was able to use $resource like we are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `run()`, use `config()` with `$httpProvider`:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {
        'RemoteUser': 'billybob'
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clinicalApp.run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json, charset=UTF-8";
});
```

Comment: Where is this added at?

Comment: @jhamm I modified my answer.